# Adding CMS Blocks to a Products, not programatically - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, cms, cms-block, magento-2.1.9

I would like to add additional information to specified products, we would like to use the block as a template where we would just need to add this block to the product content so it would appear without problem in the products we desire.

This is the block:

[image]

Here is the product content:

[image]

But it doesn't show up after the text we already have:

[image]

We would like this to not be programatically, so someone who doesn't have acces to the code, only to the magento website can manage  to make all the changes needed.

Comment: No, I mean using the backend only, the Magento configuration. You can't do much stuff on the frontend. But I say that in the title because there must be a way to do it programatically, but it doesn't suit what I need.

Comment: so basically you want to show the block into the tab of product page right?

Comment: Either inside the tab or under. Once I know how to call it there I will adjust as I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Below extension might help you if you don't want to do it programmatically.**

https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/custom-static-blocks/

However just in case if you want to do it programmatically, it can be done by below.

> **Navigate to:** Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and call the block there as below

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product.extraproduct.tab" as="extraproduct.tab" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">extra product</argument>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">extra_product</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
      </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

Flush the cache once done

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I just told you that I can't do it programatically, it doesn't suit what I need. Thank you for your answer but it's not what I ask for.

Comment: without calling a static block in file, how magento can identify where you need to put it?
anyways I don't think what you ask for is possible without doing a code

Comment: It might not be possible but I just want to ask if someone has done it earlier, or knows how, or knows about a extension or whatever :D

Comment: May be this can help https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/custom-static-blocks/

Comment: Answer with the extension, I will accept it.

Comment: I have edited my previous answer and thank you :)